# Unity failed to present D3D11 swapchain due to device reset/removed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I open unity, I try and open the project it takes like an hour and then this error happens:

```
Unity failed to present D3D11 swapchain due to device reset/removed.
```

It happens for all branches of the project and as far as I’m aware I didn’t do anything just checked out a later commit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure D3Dcompiler_47.dll file is present in "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\Your unity version\Editor\Data\Tools" or "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\Your unity version\Editor".

Comment: It is in the folder but still having that error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the solution.
This error comes due high load of graphics in the project.
step1: open your project in unity
step2:click "Edit" and then click "Project         Settings"
step3:click"Quality"
step4:Then change levels to "low" then save it
step5:Exit from unity
step6:Restart your pc

watch vedio till end thanx

https://youtu.be/AWDgoMPxoB4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).